# Do the projection (with Jacobian) and marginalisation (inversion of matrix and remove a row/column and reinversion) commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, python, matrix, projection, sympy

I try to check the equality or the inequality between 2 Fisher matrices.

**The goal is too see if the projection (with Jacobian) and marginalisation (inversion of matrix and remove a row/column and reinversion) commute.**

Each of these 2 matrices is computed slightly differently. These 2 matrices are Fisher matrices.

Actually, this is the computation of changing parameters between initial parameters for each row/colum and final parameters for the final matrix. That's why in both computations, I am using the Jacobian J formulating the derivatives between initial and final parameters :

The formula is : $F_{\text{final}} = J^T F_{\text{initial}} J$

The first matrix has size 5x5 and the second one has 4x4 size. They are identical except the 4th row/column.

1. First : I inverse the 5x5 matrix (which gives a 5x5 covariance matrix). Then, I "marginalise", that is to say, I remove the 4th row/column of this covariance matrix. Then, I inverse again to get a 4x4 matrix.

Finally, I perform a projection with a Jacobian 4x4 with formula : $F_{\text{final}} = J^T F_{\text{initial}} J$ : so I get at the end a 4x4 matrix

2. For the second matrix to build : I am doing directly projection on 5x5 second matrix (which I recall is identical to the 5x5 except for the 4th row/column).

I perform this projection with the Jacobian 5x5. Then I get the second projected matrix 5x5. Finally, I remove the 4th row/column on this 5x5 matrix to get a 4x4 matrix new projected matrix.

**I wonder under which conditions I could have equality between the 2 matrices 4x4. I don't know if my method is correct.**

To show you a practical example, I put below a small Matlab script that tries to follow all the reasoning explained above :

```
clear;
clc;

% Big_31 Fisher : 
FISH_Big_1_SYM = sym('sp_', [4,4], 'real');
% Force symmetry for Big_31
FISH_Big_1_SYM = tril(FISH_Big_1_SYM.') + triu(FISH_Big_1_SYM,1);

% Big_32 Fisher : 
FISH_Big_2_SYM = sym('sp_', [5,5], 'real');
% Force symmetry for Big_32
FISH_Big_2_SYM = tril(FISH_Big_2_SYM.') + triu(FISH_Big_2_SYM,1);

% Jacobian 1 
J_1_SYM = sym('j_', [4,4], 'real');
% Jacobian 2 
J_2_SYM = sym('j_', [5,5], 'real');

% Remove 3th row/column
J_2_SYM(4,:) = [];
J_2_SYM(:,4) = [];

% Projection
FISH_proj_1 = J_1_SYM'*FISH_Big_1_SYM*J_1_SYM;
size(FISH_proj_1)

% Invert Fisher_2
COV_Big_2_SYM = inv(FISH_Big_2_SYM);

% Remove 3th row/column
COV_Big_2_SYM(5,:) = [];
COV_Big_2_SYM(:,5) = [];

% Re-inverse
FISH_Big_2_SYM_new = inv(COV_Big_2_SYM);

% Projection 2x2
FISH_proj_2 = J_2_SYM'*FISH_Big_2_SYM_new*J_2_SYM;
size(FISH_proj_2)

% Test equality between 2 matrices
isequal(FISH_proj_1,FISH_proj_2)
```

The problem with this script is even I have small matrices (5x5 or 6x6), the code is very
slow with Matlab Symbolic at execution and I can't conclude up to now.

I hope to have been clear, don't hesitate me to ask for further information if my explanations are not enough precise.

Comment: Can you write down the formulas that correspond to the two different ways of finding your $3\times 3$ matrices? Removing a row/column corresponds to multiplication with a particular, rectangular matrix, so you should be able to write down formulas for both of the two ways you state.

Comment: Write it down as an actual formula, including the removal of the row/column, for both cases. Use math markup with dollar signs for formulas to make it easy to read.

Comment: I give up. I just want to see what you describe in words as formulas.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth . I have added some precision on the question : this could be summarized by the titlle : Do the projection (with Jacobian) and marginalisation (inversion of matrix and remove a row/column and reinversion) commute ? I hope you will understand

Comment: Why is it so hard to write this down in a formula? If an inversion is involved, there ought to be a $X^{-1}$ somewhere, but no such formula can be found.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth . Yes, I don't know how to formulate in matricial point of view the marginalisation, i.e to write down the fact that we remove a row/column on a matrix. How could I translate this operation ?

Comment: It corresponds to multiplication with a matrix that is equal to the identity matrix with one row or column removed.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth . I think this a little bit tricky : I talk about to remove a line/row, not setting a line/colum of zeros in the new matrix, this is different, do you understand ? . Here, the  size of new matrix is decrease from 1.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and my suggestion continues to be correct.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth ok, I think that I got it, I thought you meant set a row/column of zeros in identity matrix. apologies, I am going to try to translate it analytically. Thanks